# JQuery in external .js file not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having problems running a simple jQuery script in an external js file.

```
$("#main-nav").click(function(){
   alert("hello");
});`
```

I declared the external js file here in my html after the jQuery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalfile.js"></script>`
```

Nothing happens when I load the page and I get no errors in the console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you better, it would be useful if you included details such as what exact error or issue you are encountering, what you have tried to fix it, and any other information to give more context surrounding your problem.

Comment: move those scripts before closing body tag </body>  and try running it if you are declaring those script tags in head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a guess since there isn't enough information here, but I'm relatively certain you've placed these `<script>` tags in your `<head>`, where they will be executed before the DOM is ready.  Since the DOM isn't ready, you can't bind a click event to it.  Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(documment).ready(function () {
  $("#main-nav").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

Now your code to bind the click handler will run after the DOM is ready and able to have events bound to it.